# Mapping AD "member of" user property in sharepoint 2010 user profile properties

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, user-profile-property

I need to map AD's "Member Of" property in sharepoint 2010 user profile properties. I found a guide on how to do that, [How to map a user’s Active Directory group membership to their SharePoint profile](http://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/how-to-map-active-directory-security-groups-to-a-sharepoint-user-profile/) but unfortunately it refers to sharepoint 2007, and to be honest I was hoping that meanwhile there was some faster/easier way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the idea of running the scheduled powershell, you can resort to a WebPart in the profile (person.aspx) page.

But beware that doing direct queries to AD can bite you back for it was not built to be queried extensively (there is a good reason SharePoint synchronizes and makes a local copy of the domain), but your use case may fit in it.

That said, your web part just needs to run this `DirectoryServices` query:

```
public List<string> GetMemberships(string username)
{
   var empty = new List<string>();
   var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
   var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, username);

   if(user == null)
       return empty; //empty result or throw ex

   return user.GetAuthorizationGroups().OfType<GroupPrincipal>().Select(g => g.DistinguisedName).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, I did this in 2007 last week, and it was easy in the corresponding User Profile Synchronization Service in the dialogue for mapping AD properties to SharePoint...
I guess it hasn't changed much in 2010, but if there's a simpler way, I'm happy to know too :)

Comment: In the end I decided it would be *easier and faster* to just retrieve the group members through an LDAP query to the AD. Of course doing it, being the first time I try, is a whole different matter but still better then wasting time trying something of which I have even less info and examples to look to.

Comment: How did you do that? I also want to add new Userprofile property, which sync with the field "Memeber Of" in AD.